# Why is my button text not showing when switching fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making an android application for my internship so I'm not that good yet. I got five fragments that all show different content about the company. The first fragment is immediatly loaded at the `onCreate()` of the MainActivity. On the first fragment I got 6 buttons that will direct to other the other fragments(except one that will use a "call" function). The title of the buttons will be filled by an xml feed of the company its website(this all works fine).

**How I want it:**

When I switch to another fragment (Services which is fragment 2) and switch back to fragment 1 (Home fragment) it will take the stored values of the xml feed and refill the titles of the buttons.

**What is happening and is my problem:**
When I switch to another fragment from home and back to the home fragment my home fragment button titles wont be filled with the stored data.

**Code where it happens:**

```
public void selectItem(int position) {


    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    position_array_items = position;        
    simple_array = fragment_items.toArray(new String[fragment_items.size()]);

    if (position == 4) {
       // this is the call function and won't show a title for the actionbar
    }else{
        setTitle(simple_array[position]);
    }

    Fragment_a fragment_a = new Fragment_a();
    Fragment_b fragment_b = new Fragment_b();
    Fragment_c fragment_c = new Fragment_c();
    Fragment_d fragment_d = new Fragment_d();
    Fragment_e fragment_e = new Fragment_e();

    switch (position) {

    case 0:                 
        if (!fragment_a.isVisible()) {              
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment_a, "fragmentA");
            transaction.addToBackStack("fragmentA");

            transaction.commit();           
        }

        Button button_main_menu_one = config.button_main_menu_one;
        Button button_main_menu_two = config.button_main_menu_two;
        Button button_main_menu_three = config.button_main_menu_three;
        Button button_main_menu_four = config.button_main_menu_four;
        Button button_main_menu_five = config.button_main_menu_five;
        Button button_main_menu_six = config.button_main_menu_six;

        button_main_menu_one.setText(config.fragment_title_1);// Home
        button_main_menu_two.setText(config.fragment_title_2);// Services
        button_main_menu_three.setText(config.fragment_title_3);// About us
        button_main_menu_four.setText(config.fragment_title_4);// Opening times
        button_main_menu_five.setText(config.fragment_title_5);// Call
        button_main_menu_six.setText(config.fragment_title_6);// Contact


        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;

    case 1:                 
        if (!fragment_b.isVisible()) {              
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment_b, "fragmentB");
            transaction.addToBackStack("fragmentB");
            transaction.commit();
        }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case 2:     
        if (!fragment_c.isVisible()) {              
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment_c, "fragmentC");
            transaction.addToBackStack("fragmentC");
            transaction.commit();
        }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case 3:     
        if (!fragment_d.isVisible()) {              
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment_d, "fragmentD");
            transaction.addToBackStack("fragmentD");
            transaction.commit();
        }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    case 4:     
        String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 5:     
        if (!fragment_e.isVisible()) {              
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment_e, "fragmentE");
            transaction.addToBackStack("fragmentE");
            transaction.commit();
        }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
    default:            
        break;
    }                       
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue as following: I used to set the text on click on the item in the navigation drawer but somehow it did set the value but not showing it. I went to the fragment class and initialized the buttons there and set the text and it worked.